# jquery show and hide on same link click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a div and I want to show and hide on a link click. Not two different links to show and hide but only one.
I have used toggle() but its not working for me..

Here is the code

```
<a id="showhidediv">show-hide</a>
<div id="maindiv">
 <div id="innerleftdiv" style="width:49%;float:left">
 </div>
 <div id="innerrightdiv" style="width:49%;float:left">
 </div>
<div>

<script text="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function){
    $("showhidediv").click(function(){
      $("maindiv").hide()
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are wanting to show and hide? The link itself? Are you wanting it to blink, because jQuery has the blink effect that you could use.

Comment: I am just trying to slide the maindiv. toggle() is not working for me..and I am not able find the problem. Is there a way to use the same link to show and hide??

Comment: @shanthiram: Please see my solution for working demos.

Comment: hide() functions works well but not toggle()..is there a way around this??
thanks..

Comment: try adding "display:block" to your styles (in the style attribute, not via css file). AFAIR that is sometimes needed for the toggle function to work.

Comment: You need to include "#" in your selector.

Comment: Thanks every one for trying to answer the question and every one was right..
I found the solution . The following is the jquery function

$("#showhide").click(function() { 

                if ($("#maindiv").is(":visible")) {

                    $("#maindiv").hide();

                }
                else if($("#maindiv").is(":hidden")) {
                    $("#maindiv").show();
                }
            });

Comment: @shanthiram: That solution is ignoring a major problem with your project. If `$.toggle()` isn't working, you've got a serious problem someplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one for trying to answer the question and every one was right..

I found the solution . The following is the jquery function

```
$("#showhide").click(function() { 
  if ( $("#maindiv").is(":visible") ) { 
    $("#maindiv").hide(); 
  } else if ( $("#maindiv").is(":hidden") ) { 
    $("#maindiv").show(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works. If you're unable to get this to work for you particular project, the problem is elsewhere, and not with the toggle method or the jQuery syntax:

```
$(function(){
  $("a#showhidediv").click(function(){
    $("#maindiv").toggle();
  });
});
```

From your comments, it may be the case that you want to use $.slideToggle() instead:

```
$(function(){
  $("a#showhidediv").click(function(){
    $("#maindiv").slideToggle();
  });  
});
```

With two floated elements, you may want to modify your markup a bit:

```
<div id="maindiv">
  <div style="width:49%;float:left;">Foo</div>
  <div style="width:49%;float:left;">Bar</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

All of this works as expected as demonstrated in this online demo: http://jsbin.com/anaxi/edit and using slideToggle in this demo: http://jsbin.com/anaxi/2/edit

Comment: I tried both methods toggle and slideToggle..they do not hide the div.

Comment: @shanthiram: They do. Make sure jQuery is referenced, and that you are not mispelling anything.

Comment: @shanthiram: Jonathan's code should work perfectly. Have you accidentally given another div the same id ("maindiv")?

Answer (score 2):

This should work (*with the toggle*)

```
$('#showhidediv').click( function() { $('#maindiv').toggle();return false; } );
```

Comment: toggle() works fine in other case but did not work in mine..
Thanks for tyring.

Answer (score 1):

The following usually works.

```
$('#showhidediv').click(function(e) {
    $('#maindiv').toggle();
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop navigation
});
```

What it does is call toggle() on the div you want to show/hide. If you have several of this links and the toggle div always follows the link you can do something like this:

```
$('.showhide').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop navigation
});
```

And the HTML code would look like this:

```
<a class="showhide">Foo</a>
<div>show me / hide me</div>

<a class="showhide">Bar</a>
<div>show me / hide me</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplish this by changing the link text based on the visibility of the div you want to toggle.

```
if ($("#divToToggle").is(":visible"))
   $("#linkId")[0].innerText = "show";
else
   $("#linkId")[0].innerText = "hide";

$("#divToToggle").toggle();
```

If toggle is not working for you for some reason just use show() and hide() on divToToggle

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
$('#showhidediv').click(function(){
  $('#maindiv').toggle();
  return false; // should return false to prevent page loading
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above should work.  I can't imagine that it would be something in CSS that would prevent this from working.

What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you could probable try this out

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('maindiv');">show-hide</a>
     <div id="maindiv">
          #....content goes here.....
     <div>

 <script text="text/javascript">
   function toggleDiv(divId) {
      $("#"+divId).toggle();
   }
 </script>
```

works for me, also checkout this [link](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/)

Comment: @shanthiram this should work, was also struggling on this for a while

Answer (score -1):

**Javascript code :**

```
$(".user-profile-info").unbind().click(function(){

    if($( ".user-profile-info" ).hasClass("collapsed")){

         $('#user-profile-submenu').css('display', 'block');
         $( ".user-profile-info" ).removeClass("collapsed");
    }

    else
    {       
         $( ".user-profile-info" ).addClass("collapsed");
         $('#user-profile-submenu').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="user-profile-info collapsed"></div>
<div id="user-profile-submenu">Content of click</div>
```

Comment: HTML code would look like this:<div class="user-profile-info collapsed"></div>