# JavaScript Read More / Read Less

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Can someone help me with this issue, i need to hide and show content between two elements, which are represented by read more and read less buttons. In my example it works fine, but my problem  is when i click 'Read More' button it should hide, and 'Read Less' should appear, and vice versa.
I need to keep those anchor elements, because this text should be translatable be end user, so they wouldn't have access to javascript code.
Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-info').hide();
      $('.read-more').click(function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('.read-less').show();

        })
      $('.read-less').click(function(){
        $(this).prevUntil('.read-more').hide();

      })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More </a>
  <div class="service-info">

    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
  </div>
<a href="#" class="read-less">Read Less</a>


<div class="separator"><hr></div>


<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More </a>
  <div class="service-info">

    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>

  </div>
<a href="#" class="read-less">Read Less</a>
```

Comment: Try searching the [tag:jquery] tag, and you will probably find an answer to your question. You are simply asking how to hide and show an element based on a click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery show and hide on same link click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239658/jquery-show-and-hide-on-same-link-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is wrap those with an `div` then hide/show what you want. And make `read-less` invisible by default.

See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qe06xux5/

Html should look like:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More </a>
    <div class="service-info">

      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
      <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    </div>
  <a href="#" class="read-less">Read Less</a>
</div>
```

And Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.service-info').hide();
   $('.read-more').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.service-info').show();
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).parent().find('.read-less').show();
   });

   $('.read-less').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.service-info').hide();
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).parent().find('.read-more').show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebckew4k/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-info').hide();
    $('.read-less').hide();
      $('.read-more').click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).next().show();
          $(this).next().next().show();
        })
      $('.read-less').click(function(){
        $(this).prev().hide();
          $(this).prev().prev().show();
          $(this).hide();
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is pretty simple and your code looks already fine, a really simple answer could be this. Not the best one though!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.service-info').hide();
       $('.read-less').hide();
       $('.read-more').click(function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('.read-less').show();
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).next().next().show();
        })
       $('.read-less').click(function(){
         $('.read-less').hide();
         $('.read-more').show()
         $(this).prevUntil('.read-more').hide();
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maye you wold like to look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0x4utwym/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.service-info').hide();
  $('.read-more').click(function() {
    $('.service-info').hide();
    $(this).nextUntil('.read-less').show();

  })
  $('.read-less').click(function() {
    $(this).prevUntil('.read-more').hide();

  })
})
```

What basically I am doing here is hiding hiding the info just after the click event. The rest of your code seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using css:

First define the html with the long text and the read more / less buttons:

```
<p>
    <span id="longtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, wisi quas ligula fusce. Non libero aliquam ipsum suscipit wisi, leo erat dui mollis sem lacinia, justo tempora sem duis sem sagittis faucibus. Ac placerat platea felis, nisl vivamus aliquam wisi senectus gravida, nec urna odio eu. Curabitur ab, varius quis imperdiet, magna neque natoque augue rhoncus, mauris vel rhoncus, sit urna in sed sodales diam. In suscipit wisi, ut pretium ac curabitur luctus, pellentesque sed tempus ut feugiat. Vel nec nibh eleifend adipiscing, lectus egestas viverra maecenas, vehicula metus lorem nunc ut justo, pellentesque in interdum quis. Pede enim, faucibus non dictum erat etiam in accumsan. Praesent et dictum sit massa. Integer vivamus quis orci platea est lectus, vestibulum morbi nam mauris, est commodo nulla pulvinar ipsum, varius phasellus sollicitudin.</span>
    <a id="readless" onclick="javascript:fncReadless();">Read less</a>
    <a id="readmore" class="hidden" onclick="javascript:fncReadmore();">Read more</a>
```

The .css:

```
.parrafContract {
    width:40%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The javascript functions:

```
function fncReadless() {
    $("#longtext").addClass("parrafContract ");
    $("#readless").hide();
    $("#readmore").show();
}

function fncReadmore() {
    $("#longtext").removeClass("parrafContract ");
    $("#readless").show();
    $("#readmore").hide();
}
```

In this case I initialice the page with showing all the long text.